# "Fusca" como coloquialismo español para hablar de dinero. ¿Cuál es el origen?

Tags: etimología, coloquialismos, españa, sinónimos

No suelo utilizar este tipo de coloquialismo pero desde que soy pequeño he escuchado cómo la palabra "fusca" se utiliza como sinónimo de "dinero". Lo he oído mencionar así en Madrid, España.

El hecho de no encontrar referencia escrita es lo que me impulsa a realizar esta pregunta porque la definición de [fusca](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=IdyosrI) según la RAE es la siguiente:

> Fusco, ca
>
> Del lat. fuscus.
>
> 1. adj. p. us. Oscuro, que tira a negro.
> 2. m. jerg. fusca (‖ pistola).
> 3. f. jerg. pistola (‖ arma de fuego corta).
> 4. f. pato negro.
> 5. f. Ext. y Sal. Maleza, hojarasca.

Y esta definición nada tiene que ver con el uso de "fusca" como significado de dinero.

Entonces, ¿cómo llegó esta palabra a transformarse?

Comment: Yo nunca he oído referirse al dinero como fusca en España, para mi siempre ha significado pistola.

Comment: Yo soy madrileño y jamás lo había oído usar así. Estás bien segura de que oíste bien el término? Puedes dar un ejemplo de uso? Si lo has oído una sola vez o de una sola persona, es posible que esa persona no esté usando bien el término o lo confunda con algún otro.

Comment: El referirse al dinero como fusca es algo que nunca he oído en Madrid; es probable que en tu ámbito cercano surgiera esa nueva acepción al evolucionar de algunos de los significados reconocidos. Por ejemplo, fusca (3ª acepción) pudo significar dinero al relacionarse las hojas con los billetes... De todas maneras, yo soy madrileño y jamás lo he oído, y al buscar en Google u otra fuente no hallo nada...

Comment: @AntónSeoane puede ser como dices. He preguntado también a algunos amigos y tampoco lo han oído. Debe ser algo de mi entorno familiar pero quería saber si alguien más lo ha oído.

Comment: En extremeño, fusca significa maleza. Aunque coloquialmente se puede utilizar como dinero.

Answer (score 3):

Basándome en mi propia experiencia como madrileño y en el respaldo de los comentarios, me atreveré a decir que `fusca` no es sinónimo de dinero.

Dependiendo de cómo se produjo esa conversación me atrevería a decir que o bien tú no oíste bien o que esa persona no usa el término correcto. Como entiendo que quien lo dijo es conocido tuyo, ya has preguntado acerca de ese uso, entiendo que ese alguien no lo está usando bien.

Yo por ejemplo oigo a mucha gente usar "quemarse a los **gonso** (o a lo *gonzo*)" cuando al expresión es realmente "quemarse a lo *bonzo*" (y el [periodismo *gonzo*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodismo_gonzo) es otra cosa completamente distinta).

Otros sinónimos válidos para `dinero`, aunque posiblemente no universales, serían:

- plata
- [parné](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RxLIPqh)
- [pasta](http://dle.rae.es/?id=S5QKx5t)
- [guita](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Js4Dc5P)
- [cuartos](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BTctS7T)
- efectivo
- metálico

Comment: Los sinónimos de dinero darían para un post interesante, seguramente en cada país o región haya una buena cantidad de ellos, se me ocurren unos cuantos de mi zona de los que no veo referencia alguna en internet.

Comment: Muy bien, diciendo las cosas como son. :)